# Strange iOS navigation app crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, calayer

I'm writing a navigation app for iPhone at the moment and I'm having a very weird crash issue and was wondering if anyone had come across (and solved) this issue.

I have two views, both of which contain UITableViews and one that uses cells loaded from a nib. When I push and pop from one view to the other, after a couple of presses (usually 7 to 10) with everything loading and displaying as it should the app suddenly crashes. The debugger shows that CALayer was the last thing running, but I don't use any custom implementation of this class.

My first thought is that I've over-released an object, but after two days of playing with the code I can't identify any zombies.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Can post parts of code if required.

UPDATE:
Looks like zombies are being created on UIView delegate methods, namely viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear. Will investigate further tomorrow. :D

Comment: try running the static analyzer to determine if there are any memory leaks. Also check the exact cause of output in the console window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to set breakpoints at the dealloc methods of the related classes, and see if the crash happens in one of the method. And also usually by looking at the callstack when the crash is happening, you can tell whether it's a memory related crash or not.

Comment: I found that one of my pushed view controllers was weirdly being overreleased. Thanks for the guidance! :D